# jQuery Blur function in Content Editor web part in SharePoint 2010 List form

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-form

Want to know how to use a jQuery blur function  for my `SPNumberField`, `single line of text` etc fields.I do not have the `ID` of the field, also how to get the ID for using the same in jQuery function?

Copying from the `viewsource` or `F12 Developer Tools` is not a good practice and I can't insert any span tag or `div` id for those fields as its a pure SP 2010 `ListForm`

Comment: You will probably get more answers from advanced users on your questions when you mark questions as answered, thats how StackOverflow works.. you give credits, you earn credits.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `id`, any selector to get a DOM element will do.

I recall from my 2007 days you can get elements by searching for the last part of the `name`

```
$(input[name$='NumberField'])
```

*or something like that*

BTW you do not need jQuery either

http://callmenick.com/post/jquery-functions-javascript-equivalents

this site will also educate you on how to attach events

Comment: I tried inside a Content Editor webpart by putting the blur function within the document. ready() but  it didn't work. That's why I posted your answer as useful.